# Check if an array has a value

Tags: java

First, have a look at this Snake-Game.

My problem is, the method `locateApple()` generate the apple on a random position.

Sometimes it spawns directly on the snake. How do I prevent this?

A way could be to check the Array of Snake's body. But I dont know how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: how can you expect some one to trace out your error code

Comment: Hint: you need a loop and a `boolean` variable.

Comment: Can you show some code or explain your problem more detailed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a `Coordinate` class that holds 2 values for `x` and `y`. This class has methods like:

- `int getX();` to get the value of the `x` coordinate
- `int getY();` to get the value of the `y` coordinate

Now you also need a `CoordinateContainer` class that holds a number of Coordinates.
 The Coordinate container class can have (among others..) methods like :

- `void add(Coordinate x);` to add a Coordinate.
- `Coordinate getCoordinate(Coordinate x);` to get a Coordinate
- `boolean contains(Coordinate x); to check if the container contains a specific coordinate.

and so on.

Now you can represent a snake as a `CoordinateContainer`.

The implementation of the `contains` method can look like this:

```
public boolean contains(Coordinate x){
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfCoordinates; i++) //numOfCoordinates is an int holding how many Coordinates you have passed in the array.
        if(array[i].getX() == x.getX() && array[i].getY() == x.getY()) return true;
    return false; // Compare value of X,Y of each Coordinate with the respective X,Y of the parameter Coordinate.
}
```

Now that you have a way to check if a `Coordinate` is contained in a `CoordinateContainer` you are good to go. The method to place apples can look like this:

```
private void placeNewApple(){
    Coordinate newApple = apples.getRandom(); //<-- getRandom() returns a random Coordinate within the board        
    while(snake.contains(newApple)){
        newApple = apples.getNew();
    }
    placeApple(newApple);// method to place an apple at newApple.getX() , newApple.getY();
}
```

Hope this makes sense

**NOTE:** If you don't have to/want to do it this way, i.e with seperate classes, and you only have an `Array` in a main programm please add some code to your questions and i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can discard the apple and try a new location if it is no proper location...

```
Point position = null;
do{
    Point candidate = createRandomLocation();
    double distance = measureDistance(head, candidate);    
    if (distance > 20) { //maybe you check other things as well...
        position = new Poisition(candidate)
    }
}while(position ==null);
```